# Word cutting off the sides of my word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

When I print a word a document the sides are cut off. When normally view it (while editing) the full document appears, when in print view the sides are cut off. I have set no margins and this still occurs. Any ideas how to fix this? Also, how would you make the header show from underneath the picture?
[Edit view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQgIo.jpg)
[Print View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKdlR.jpg)
[Printed View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4zrn.jpg)
(Please excuse low picture quality as superuser does not allow large files!)

Comment: Does it print on printer exactly the same as in the Print View? Do you really want the printed version not to have any margins?

Comment: The print view takes into account that a printer usually cannot print up to the page border. You'll have to set borderless printing in your printers options dialogue

Comment: Thanks I just needed to turn on borderless printing. This fixed all issues.

Comment: @Asjal Please post that comment as an answer. You are welcome to self-solve answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Only for printers with borderless printing on Windows 11:

Open Settings > Bluetooth and devices > Printers and scanners

Click on your printer > Printing preferences > Advanced

And set Borderless printing to **On**
[image]